# Can I map multiple AD groups to multiple roles on ESXi?

Tags: active-directory, vmware-esxi, authorization

I have an AD joined ESXi server (v7.0) without a vCenter server. I can map an AD group to the "Administrator" role by configuring the advanced setting `Config.HostAgent.Plugins.Hostsvc.EsxAdminsGroup`. But is that all? Can I not map an AD group to the "Read only" role, for example?

Comment: https://www.net-pioneers.com/vsphere-rbac-part-ii-allow-ad-user-to-mansge-esxi/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map groups to roles via the following path in vSphere Web Client:

1. Right-click on *Host* or on *Manage*
2. Click on *Permissions*